# Mysql update column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables `fullInfo` and `fundInfo`.  `fullInfo` is a full data set of donations to a non-profit.  `fundInfo` is a list of unique fund subgroups with accompanying id numbers.  I'm trying to insert the fund id number from `fundInfo` into `fullInfo` in a column fundId that exists but currently has NULL values.

`fullInfo`:

```
id          funddesc          amount        fundId
002         GENERAL           25.00          NULL
044         MAINT             50.00          NULL
122         TRAVEL            75.00          NULL
...          ...               ...            ...
```

`fundInfo`:

```
id          funddesc
01           MAINT
02           TRAVEL
03           GENERAL
...            ...

update fullInfo
set fullInfo.fundId = fundInfo.id
where fullInfo.funddesc = fundInfo.funddesc;
```

This code is not working.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE fullInfo
    INNER JOIN fundInfo
        ON fullInfo.funddesc = fundInfo.funddesc
    SET fullInfo.fundId = fundInfo.id;
```

Comment: It is interesting to compare the two styles offered.  I prefer the style I offered (obviously), but this is because to me it is clearer which table is the one being updated.  If there were multiple joins, I would use the inner join ... on... syntax under the FROM, but in so doing I still keep them separate from the main UPDATE table clause.

Answer (score 3):

```
update fullInfo
set fullInfo.fundId = fundInfo.id
from
fundInfo
where fullInfo.funddesc = fundInfo.funddesc;
```